# ios 7.0 simulator doesn't download in xcode 6.0.1

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, xcode6

Could not download and install iOS 7.0 Simulator. Failed to mount file:///Users//Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode/Downloads/Xcode.SDK.iPhoneSimulator.7.0-7.0.dmg at file:///var/folders/p0/94d17pz545l9w47byr0z2gzcr14jm4/T/attached-image-0f91fbf058f8f65f6ddbe8e8e28dbeaa6b366f89/: image not recognized[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like perhaps your download got corrupted.  I suggest you delete ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode and retry.

Comment: I deleted old ios simulator folder which is in Library folder.Now iOS 7.0 simulator is downloaded.Thanks for help Jeremy Huddleston Sequoia...

Comment: @SASSudalaiyandi - how did u solved ur problem? can give us the folder path to delete old ios simulator folder. Thank you.

Comment: The problem wasn't an old simulator folder. The issue was the Xcode cache of the download was somehow corrupted.  It would be nice to figure out a way to reproduce the issue (perhaps you could create a tarball of your cache and host it somewhere for me to download).  If you just want to nuke the cache and be on your way to fix the problem, just delete ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode